# How to use Mongo Aggregation Pipeline to format array?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this document as part of an Aggregation Pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "mfe_average": [
      [
        true,
        5.352702824879613
      ],
      [
        false,
        3.2361364317753383
      ],
      [
        null,
        2.675027181819201
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

How to convert to this format? Only the true values are Valid.

```
[
  {
    "mfe_average": [
      [
        "Valid",
        5.352702824879613
      ],
      [
        "Invalid",
        3.2361364317753383
      ],
      [
        "Invalid",
        2.675027181819201
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The query may look complex.

1. `$map` - Iterates the element in `mfe_average` and returns a new array.

   1.1. `$concatArrays` - Combine arrays into one.

   1.1.1. `$cond` - Set the value ("Valid"/"Invalid") by getting the first item of the nested array and comparing the value. It results in an array.

   1.1.2. `$slice` - Take all the values in the nested array except the first item.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      mfe_average: {
        $map: {
          input: "$mfe_average",
          as: "avg",
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              [
                {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            "$$avg",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        true
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "Valid",
                    else: "Invalid"
                  }
                }
              ],
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$$avg",
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      {
                        $subtract: [
                          {
                            $size: "$$avg"
                          },
                          1
                        ]
                      },
                      -1
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U4pyDdsYfzG)

---

If your nested array contains only 2 items, you may not require to write the complex `$slice` query as above. Instead, just provide `-1` to take the last item of the nested array.

```
{
  $slice: [
    "$$avg",
    -1
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$map` operator to reconstruct the array,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `mfe_average` array
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific position's element from array
- `$cond` to check if the first element is true then return "Valid" otherwise "Invalid"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      mfe_average: {
        $map: {
          input: "$mfe_average",
          in: [
            {
              $cond: [
                { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 0] },
                "Valid",
                "Invalid"
              ]
            },
            { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 1] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HBucnZqNCk6)